# Calculate lead-time between selected rows (SQL)

Tags: sql

Given this table where we have users, the product that they used, and the first date that they used the product (I have also created a simple rank by user window). Note, each user will only have minimum 0 rows if they used nothing before, and 2 rows, if they used both products. There are only 3 products - cigars and beers.

[image]

How can I create a new view where each row is 1 user, the next column shows the first product, the next column shows the 2nd product, and the last column shows the lead-time b/w the first dates of use?

[image]

Comment: Use windows function based on your  DB

Comment: Cigars and beers are three products?

Answer (score 0):

One method is conditional aggregation with `row_number()`:

```
select user,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then product end) as product_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then product end) as product_2,
       (max(case when seqnum = 2 then time_used end) -
        max(case when seqnum = 1 then time_used end)
       ) as dif
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by user order by time_used) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by user;
```

Date/time functions vary significantly across different databases.  Not all support a simple `-`, so you might nee to adjust for your database.

Answer (score 0):

## Minus between dates may not work on each database

```
select
    c1.user_id,
    c1.first_product_used,
    c2.second_product_used,
    COALESCE(CAST((Cast(c2.second_date AS DATE) - Cast(c1.first_date AS DATE)) AS VARCHAR(20)), 'n/a') AS "leadtime_days"
from
    (
    select
        user_id,
        product_used AS first_product_used,
        time_used AS first_date
    from
        check2
    where
        rank_of_use = 1
    )c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
    select
        user_id,
        product_used AS second_product_used,
        time_used AS second_date
    from
        check2
    where
        rank_of_use = 2
    )c2
ON
    c1.user_id = c2.user_id
```